# How do I create tenant specific locale overrides for @nuxt-i18n locale files in Nuxt 3 project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, nuxt3, nuxt-i18n

I have a Nuxt 3 project that's using [@nuxtjs/i18n (v8.2.0)](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/) and I'm trying to create an override system that allows tenants to override the existing locale strings in the application by merging the existing locale file with a tenant specific override file.

I have a system that works currently that uses an `i18n.config.ts` file that manually imports each file I need. The imports use an import alias that I've defined in my `nuxt.config.ts` (@tenant).

How do I do this more efficiently so that I dynamically import all the locale files and associated override files automatically rather than manually importing and merging each locale file and creating the final `messages` object in the `i18n.config.ts`?

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
  ],
  i18n: {
    vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts',
  },
  alias: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/prefer-global/process
    '@tenant': `./assets/${process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_TENANT_ID}`,
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      tenantId: '',
    },
  },
})
```

```js
// i18n.config.ts
import deepmerge from 'deepmerge'

import tenantEn from '@tenant/locales/en.json'
import tenantAr from '@tenant/locales/ar.json'

import en from './locales/en.json'
import ar from './locales/ar.json'

export default defineI18nConfig(() => {
  const messages = {
    en: deepmerge(en, tenantEn),
    ar: deepmerge(ar, tenantAr),
  }

  return {
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'ar'],
    messages,
  }
})
```

```json
// locales/en.json
{
  "public": {
    "login": {
      "title": "Welcome!"
    }
  }
}

// 
assets/my-tenant/locales/en.json
{
  "public": {
    "login": {
      "title": "Welcome to the tenant string party!"
    }
  }
}
```

Folder structure:

```
locales/en.json <- standard language strings
assets/my-tenant/locales/en.json <- client specific overrides
```